# What's the status of LevelDB? Is it safe for use in production?

Tags: production-environment, leveldb

Does anyone know how well tested LevelDB is and what is its status for use in production? It's a relatively new library and when I checked the source code it didn't appear to be handling errors too well. Does anyone use LevelDB in production and can comment on my question?

Comment: Heya, I downvoted this because it appears to be a subjective, opinion-based question.  Stack Overflow generally avoids these sorts of things, [seeking questions that have solid answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).  I'd expect an answerable question to specifically ask what functions in the library would need additional error checking to be reliable or what virtues LevelDB has vs. <other key/value store solution>.  If this question doesn't work out, try asking another with this in mind.  Hope you find the answers you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

We use LevelDB in our website, but wrapped in SSDB(https://github.com/ideawu/ssdb), the LevelDB network server, with hash/zset data types support. Our SSDB instance serves 100 million queries per day.

Comment: How has the stability of leveldb been? Any issues you've run into?

Comment: Both LevelDB an SSDB is production ready. LevelDB write data in sequence, and then compact(merge) in a seperated thread, so the performace may slow down during the compaction, because disk IO would fill up. SSDB adds compaction IO speed limit feature to LevelDB.

Answer (score 2):

LevelDB has a lot of high-visibility problems https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/2770 and the code is so poorly written that a bounty was needed to find a fix https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=337294.0;all And the leveldb discussion group is predominantly bug reports about very fundamental database functionality that fails to work as advertised. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/leveldb (e.g., "snapshots" aren't actually snapshots, and can be tainted by subsequent writes https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leveldb/IAKJaL2zqZM etc...)

On the date that this question was asked, LevelDB was certainly NOT production ready and anyone who thought so was delusional. The code quality is abysmal, as confirmed by independent developers https://twitter.com/rescrv/status/406106256890286080

Answer (score 1):

One place it is used in a production environment is the Bitcoin project. Within bitcoin, it's usage is critical for the security of the platform. See the release notes for [Bitcoin QT 0.8.0](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.8.0/doc/release-notes.txt)

Comment: And it has caused no end of problems in bitcoin. https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/2770 and the problem is so bad and the code is so poorly written that a bounty was needed to find a fix https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=337294.0;all And the leveldb discussion group is predominantly bug reports about very fundamental database functionality that fails to work as advertised. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/leveldb

On the date that this question was asked, LevelDB was certainly NOT production ready and anyone who thought so was delusional.

Answer (score -1):

How do you qualify "relatively new" as it was out in 2011?

Can you please give more detail on "not handling errors too well"?

LevelDB is used as a backend in Riak and Hyperdex, which have both customised it to improve throughput under huge loads. There **was** <s>a great [video from Ricon East 2013](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vo88IdglU_8) explaining the Riak changes made by Basho.</s> (taken down at some point prior to 2019-03).

Note that [RocksDB](https://rocksdb.org/) is another major fork, by Facebook, which is recommended for serverside. History of it forking from LevelDB is on [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RocksDB). You can read about how RocksDB handles errors on [this page](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Background-Error-Handling):

> Currently in RocksDB, any error during a write operation (write to
> WAL, Memtable Flush, background compaction etc) causes the database
> instance to go into read-only mode by default and further user writes
> are not accepted....
>
> Call DB::Resume() to manually resume the DB and put it in read-write
> mode. This function will clear the error, purge any obsolete files,
> and restart background flush and compaction operations. At present, it
> only supports resuming from background errors that happen during
> compaction. In the future, we will add more cases.